# Estou aprendendo, então e uma pergunta básica

Tags: c#, variáveis, console

Gostaria de saber por que depois, quando o programa foi executado, não chega a mostrar `Console.WriteLine("nome: {0}", nome);` na tela?

```
        string endereço, cpf, telefone, nome;

        Console.WriteLine("Digite o nome. ");
        nome = Console.ReadLine();


        Console.WriteLine("Digite o endereço.");
        endereço = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Digite o CPF.");
        cpf = Console.ReadLine();


        Console.WriteLine("Digite o telefone");
        telefone = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("nome: {0}", nome);
        Console.WriteLine("endereço: {0}", endereço);
        Console.WriteLine("CPF: {0}", cpf);
        Console.WriteLine("telefone: {0}", telefone);
```

Comment: Já que está aprendendo pode ver um jeito mais moderno de fazer: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qeOOI2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando executa o programa ele realiza o WriteLine mas sai imediatamente

Pode aguardar que uma teclar seja premida antes de sair

```
            string endereço, cpf, telefone, nome;

            Console.WriteLine("Digite o nome. ");
            nome = Console.ReadLine();


            Console.WriteLine("Digite o endereço.");
            endereço = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Digite o CPF.");
            cpf = Console.ReadLine();


            Console.WriteLine("Digite o telefone");
            telefone = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("nome: {0}", nome);
            Console.WriteLine("endereço: {0}", endereço);
            Console.WriteLine("CPF: {0}", cpf);
            Console.WriteLine("telefone: {0}", telefone);


            //assim execução vai ficar suspensa até que pressione uma tecla


            Console.WriteLine("Prima uma tecla para Sair");
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu até fiz um teste com seu código e ele funcionou normalmente conforme o print abaixo, não sei como você estava executando ele, se você simplesmente dava 2 clicks no executável, se rodava direto pelo Visual Studio ou se você ia no console (cmd) e digitava o nome do .exe para executar o programa. Nessa última opção você iria ver que funciona normalmente, pois ele não fecharia a tela ao término da execução.
Se você adicionar um simples Console.ReadLine(); no final do código vai ver que ele para nessa linha (aguardando um enter) depois de exibir os valores, e só depois que der o enter ele fechará a janela do aplicativo (se estivesse rodando no console ele manteria a janela do console aberto).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
        string endereço, cpf, telefone, nome;

        Console.WriteLine("Digite o nome. ");
        nome = Console.ReadLine();


        Console.WriteLine("Digite o endereço.");
        endereço = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Digite o CPF.");
        cpf = Console.ReadLine();


        Console.WriteLine("Digite o telefone");
        telefone = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("nome: {0}", nome);
        Console.WriteLine("endereço: {0}", endereço);
        Console.WriteLine("CPF: {0}", cpf);
        Console.WriteLine("telefone: {0}", telefone);


        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Obrigado Isac, corrigi na resposta.